# Sharing data among IOS App in MAC, iPhone, iPad and iWatch? Same App installed by individual user on multiple devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, keychain

Here things getting more passionate and difficult for me as a developer. I want to set up an app that would be capable to remind user for certain tasks at some specific time. The app would use LocalNotifications to remind the user.

Now, user may have this same app installed on his multiple devices, like iPhone, iPad, iWatch and MacOS. User would also change the time of those tasks and other parameters from any of the device he/she want to, I mean iPhone, iPad, iWatch or MacOS.

The operation on data amendments would then sync with all devices.

For instance, if user is having app installed on iPhone and he is set up with a tsk; i-e:
Task 
{
taskId
taskName
taskTimeData
}

A task is initialised with name 'exampleTask' in iPhone and notification and every other option is also set in iPhone. After installing same app on iPad and setting the iWatch entitlement of the app.

Now the user must also receive similar functionality on both iPad and iWatch. Similarly, changing the name/timeDate of certain specific task must also update the task in other devices also.

Also must update the time for functionality execution in all the devices.

**Please list all the available options in this regard, may become useful for other readers in future.**

**NOTE: I've gathered some of the related xCode entitlements but can't make myself understand. 
1. App Groups 
2. Keychain Sharing 
3. Cloud Kit**

*Please explain options from xCode entitlements, I'm neither interested in any third party frameworks nor in web services and third party servers.*

Comment: You just described the Apple reminders app ...

Comment: Reminders ... yes But I Want to get some info about the real implementation